# ¿Error en generar un breadcrumb usando PHP?

Tags: php

Indagando en la web, me encontré dos ejemplos que me gusta.

El primero no genera errores, es ideal como para crear un `breadcrumb` por defectos, según los datos que se obtenga de la URL.

```
<?php
$trail = array(
    'path' => 'Cool Stuff',
    'to' => 'Animals',
    'a' => 'Spiders'
);

// You could grab this automatically with $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']
$url = 'http://example.com/path/to/more/deadly/a/black_widow.php';

$parts         = parse_url($url);
$path          = pathinfo($parts['path']);
$segments      = explode('/', trim($path['dirname'],'/'));

$breadcrumbs[] = '<a href="/">Home</a>';
$crumb_path    = '';

foreach ($segments as $segment)
{
    $crumb_path .= '/' . $segment;

    $value = (array_key_exists($segment, $trail)) ? $trail[$segment] : ucfirst($segment);

    $breadcrumbs[] = '<a href="' . $crumb_path . '">' . $value . '</a>';
}

$breadcrumbs[] = ucwords(str_replace('_', ' ', $path['filename']));
$breadcrumbs   = implode(' &raquo; ', $breadcrumbs);

echo $breadcrumbs;
?>
```

Y como resultado lo siguiente:

> [Home](https://es.stackoverflow.com) » [Cool Stuff](https://es.stackoverflow.com) » [Animals](https://es.stackoverflow.com) » [More](https://es.stackoverflow.com) » [Deadly](https://es.stackoverflow.com) » [Spiders](https://es.stackoverflow.com) » Black Widow

Lo probé reemplazando los datos de la `$url`, pero existen pequeños fallos:

Por ejemplo la URL de mi sitio web:

```
example.com/productos/belleza-mujer/perfume-de-mujer/
```

Generar el breadcrumb de la siguiente manera:

> [Home](https://es.stackoverflow.com) » [Productos](https://es.stackoverflow.com) » [Belleza-mujer](https://es.stackoverflow.com) » Perfume-de-mujer

Pero el diseño del `breadcrumb` debe imprimirse así:

> [Home](https://es.stackoverflow.com) » [Productos](https://es.stackoverflow.com) » [Belleza Mujer](https://es.stackoverflow.com) » Perfume de mujer

---

En el segundo ejemplo, genera el `breadcrumb` pero ejecuta errores:

```
<?php
// This function will take $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] and build a breadcrumb based on the user's current path
function breadcrumbs($separator = ' &raquo; ', $home = 'Home') {
    // This gets the REQUEST_URI (/path/to/file.php), splits the string (using '/') into an array, and then filters out any empty values
    $path = array_filter(explode('/', parse_url($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], PHP_URL_PATH)));

    // This will build our "base URL" ... Also accounts for HTTPS :)
    $base = ($_SERVER['HTTPS'] ? 'https' : 'http') . '://' . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . '/';

    // Initialize a temporary array with our breadcrumbs. (starting with our home page, which I'm assuming will be the base URL)
    $breadcrumbs = array("<a href=\"$base\">".$home."</a>");

    // Find out the index for the last value in our path array
    //$last = end(array_keys($path));

    // Build the rest of the breadcrumbs
    foreach ($path AS $x => $crumb) {
        // Our "title" is the text that will be displayed (strip out .php and turn '_' into a space)
        $title = ucwords(str_replace(Array('.php', '_'), Array('', ' '), $crumb));

        // If we are not on the last index, then display an <a> tag
        if ($x != $last)
            $breadcrumbs[] = "<a href=\"".$base.$crumb."\">".$title."</a>";
        // Otherwise, just display the title (minus)
        else
            $breadcrumbs[] = $title;
    }

    // Build our temporary array (pieces of bread) into one big string :)
    return implode($separator, $breadcrumbs);
}

echo breadcrumbs();
?>
```

Y me imprime lo siguiente:

> [Home](https://es.stackoverflow.com) » [Productos](https://es.stackoverflow.com) » [Belleza-mujer](https://es.stackoverflow.com) > [Perfume-de-mujer](https://es.stackoverflow.com)

No elimina, los guiones `-`, en las categorías también conserva el guion, la final del la url, genera el enlace, lo cual no debe.

Y los errores son los consiguientes:

```
Notice: Undefined index: HTTPS in C:\xampp\htdocs\tienda\detalle.php on line 15

Notice: Undefined variable: last in C:\xampp\htdocs\tienda\detalle.php on line 29
```

La cual corresponde a:

```
$base = ($_SERVER['HTTPS'] ? 'https' : 'http') . '://' . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . '/'; //linea 15
    if ($x != $last) //linea 29
```

El diseño de los vínculos debe estar así:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Posiblemente este [link](https://www.codejobs.biz/es/blog/2013/03/01/breadcrumbs-en-php) pueda ser de utilidad.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Puedes pobrar de esta manera:

```
<?php
$trail = array(
   'path' => 'Cool Stuff',
   'to' => 'Animals',
   'a' => 'Spiders'
);

// You could grab this automatically with 
$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']
$url = 'http://example.com/path/to/more/deadly/a/black_widow.php';

$parts         = parse_url($url);
$path          = pathinfo($parts['path']);
$segments      = explode('/', trim($path['dirname'],'/'));

$breadcrumbs[] = '<a href="/">Home</a>';
$crumb_path    = '';

foreach ($segments as $segment) {
    $crumb_path .= '/' . $segment;

    $value = (array_key_exists($segment, $trail)) ? $trail[$segment] : ucfirst($segment);

    $breadcrumbs[] = '<a href="' . $crumb_path . '">' . str_replace(['_', '-', '+'], ' ', $value) . '</a>';
}

$breadcrumbs[] = ucwords(str_replace(['_', '-', '+'], ' ', 
$path['filename']));
$breadcrumbs   = implode(' > ', $breadcrumbs);

echo $breadcrumbs;
?>
```

Observa que en la función `str_replace` puse un Array con múltiples opciones de reemplazó las cuales son reemplazadas por espacios, en ese Array puedes agregar mas opciones a futuro

Comment: @Fernando he modificado el código, prueba con eso :)